# Finding documentary evidence for father of somebody born 1903 in Kentucky, USA?

Tags: united-states, research-methods, birth-records, death-records, kentucky

My Great Grandfather is George Ann Boyd born 1903 in Henderson Kentucky. I am looking for information on his father.

It is rumored in my family he is the father. However, I want proof.

George was raised by his aunt and uncle Annie and Everett Boyd. I don't know if he had any contact with his birth mother.

George later married Delsie Law in 1933. Delsie did not list George's father on his death certificate. My father and I were unable to obtain a Birth Certificate.

Does anybody have any ideas for how I can find reliable proof, through documents, about who was the father of George Boyd?

Comment: Andy, I've changed the title to make it more descriptive of the exact problem you're grappling with -- hope this reflects the core of the matter -- if not, you can edit it yourself with the edit button under the question.

Comment: Hi Andy, welcome to G&FH.SE.  Could you tell us how you and your father tried to get a birth certificate so we can see what you have already tried? (If you asked the state, they may have told you no because it is too early -- statewide birth records start in 1911 and there wasn't general compliance until 1920.)

Comment: I'm confused where your question says "It is rumored in my family he is the father."  Your question seems to be looking for a birth record for George Ann Boyd, so does that mean that you have a candidate (from this rumour) for the 2nd great grandfather that you are seeking?  There is an **edit** button beneath your question that you can use to clarify this detail.

Comment: Have you obtained George's SS-5 (application for a Social Security number)? It usually includes names of parents. Depending on when he died, he might not be listed in the SSDI database, but may still have had a SSN. When you attempted to get a copy of a birth certificate, did you check with his birth county?

Answer (score 2):

People with trees on Ancestry.com seem to think his parents were Samuel E. Chambers and Mary Melvana “Sis” Boyd. Don't know about the father, but I agree with the mother.

George is shown in the [1910 Census](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:M2XS-TC8) being raised by his mother and grandparents.

In the [1920 Census](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:MHPV-53R) at age 16, he had not attended school the past year, and was working as a farm hand for his Uncle James Everett Boyd.

[That same year](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:MHPV-NQV) his mother was living with her brother, Charles H. Boyd, who had been recently widowed, and had several small children.

My guess would be that Sis and George had a normal mother/son relationship, except that they both needed to work. And he moved out at a young age.

There may or may not be documentation on George's father. You'll have to search for his baptism, marriage, and social security applications to see if the father section was filled out or left blank.

Another way to prove lineage would be through DNA tests.